# Using org.apache.commons.digester.Digester in XML with attributes

Tags: java, xml, rdf, apache-commons-digester

I'm going to extract values from this XML/RDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="urn:turismoculturale.itdc.filas-1.0.0-RC1#">
 <j.0:Chiesa rdf:ID="turismoCulturale_POI_880">
   <j.0:title xml:lang="en">Church of S. Giuda Taddeo or S. Onofrio - Gaeta</j.0:title>
   <j.0:title xml:lang="it">Chiesa S. Giuda Taddeo o S. Onofrio - Gaeta</j.0:title>
 </j.0:Chiesa>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I would like to get en title when I am in "en" language and "it" title otherwise. I am able to set the title value in the Poi bean by using:

```
Digester digester = new Digester();
digester.setNamespaceAware( true );
digester.setRuleNamespaceURI( "urn:turismoculturale.itdc.filas-1.0.0-RC1#" );
digester.addObjectCreate( "*/Chiesa",  Poi.class);
digester.addBeanPropertySetter("*/title", "title");
...
```

but I don't know if it is the english title or the italian one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - first and foremost, **don't try to parse RDF/XML with an XML parser**. It's never going to work because the semantics of the XML document are irrelevant with respect to RDF/XML and it is a bad idea (if you know how RDF/XML works), especially in your case where the RDF/XML is being generated dynamically (you can tell by the namespaces). You need to use an RDF parser to parse RDF.

So that means don't use an XML to Java object mapping tool, use an RDF to Java Object mapping tool.

Here is a great link explaining how to do this:

- [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/859/best-way-to-convert-rdfxml-file-to-pojos](https://web.archive.org/web/20160601164438/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/859/best-way-to-convert-rdfxml-file-to-pojos)

And another:

- [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/3251/experience-using-java-based-frameworks-for-rdf-to-pojo-and-vice-versa-mapping](https://web.archive.org/web/20130903145151/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/3251/experience-using-java-based-frameworks-for-rdf-to-pojo-and-vice-versa-mapping)

Along with links to all the tools in the aforementioned resource:

- [Jenabean](http://code.google.com/p/jenabean/)
- [Empire](https://github.com/mhgrove/Empire)
- [AliBaba](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/alibaba/2.0-beta3/)
- [RDFReactor](http://semanticweb.org/wiki/RDFReactor)

For an out and out RDF parser, look at Jena:

- http://incubator.apache.org/jena

It's an Apache project that is also nicely Maven'ed up.

Answer (score 1):

The [Commons Digester FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/Digester/FAQ) says:

> Occasionally, people ask how they can fire a rule for an element based on the value of an attribute
>
> There is no simple way to do this with Digester; the built-in rule-matching engines only provide the ability to match on element name. There is no support available for XPath expressions
>
> It might be possible to create a custom "filtering" rule that has a child rule, and fires that child rule only when the appropriate conditions are set. There are no examples of such a solution, however.

Digester isn't a very good tool. It's too simplistic. Consider using a more comprehensive event-based API such as StAX.